# How do you return a Func<Func<string, int>, int>

Tags: c#, function, lambda

I recently figured out how to return methods/functions from methods, for example:

```
public static Func<string, int> Parse() {
    return x => Int32.Parse(x);
}
```

Out of pure curiosity I wanted to know how far I can go. Is it possible to somehow return a `Func<Func<string, int>, int>`?

```
public static Func<Func<string, int>, int> PlusSomething(this Func<string, int> parser) {
    return x => x + parser; //Obviously doesn't work
}
```

The closest thing I managed to do was

```
public static Func<string, int, int> PlusSomething(this Func<string, int> parser) {
    return (x, y) => parser(x) + y;
}
```

Comment: You have an error message or so? Why the `this` extension method prefix?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve; can you please explain the desired result a bit more?

Comment: Although the question has already been answered, I'm trying to make it a little more clear: 
Instead of having a method which takes a value and returns a value, I wanted it to take a value and return a function (which instead would then compute the value). This is what the first 3 lines of code do. 
Then I asked myself if it’s possible to create a method which takes a function as a parameter and also returns this function again (without doing any computations), plus the things the new method is actually supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not very clear what you want to achieve I am going to do a bit of guess work.

A `Func<Func<string, int>, int>` is a function that takes a function and returns an int.

One possibility is that you want to return a function that takes a function `f`, applies it to a string and returns an int. In this case you have to specify somewhere on what you want to apply the function `f`. Either when you generate the function

```
public static Func<Func<string, int>, int> PlusSomething(string s) {
    return f => f(s);
}
```

either when you apply the function

```
public static Func<Func<string, int>, int, int> PlusSomething() {
    return f, s => f(s);
}
```

Looking at your second example it seems to me (I may be wrong) that you actually want to return a function that takes a int and return a function.

```
public static Func<int, Func<string, int>> PlusSomething(Func<string, int> parser) {
    return x => (y => x + parser(y));
}
```

This would allow something like

```
var gen = PlusSomething(parser);
var parsePlus4 = gen(4);
int x = parsePlus4("8"); // x == 12
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was actually trying to refrase my question the whole time and just didn't know how. `return x => (y => x + parser(y));` is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as it is stated - yes, it is possible to have a function with the described signature as follows.

```
public static
Func<Func<string,int>,int>
PlusSomething(this Func<string, int> parser)
{
    return x => 1;
}
```

However it is unclear what the desired result is and how the input should relate to the desired output; syntactically it is possible.